Translating a c++ lambda function to a class method function in boost
I am a new self taught C++ programmer trying to learn a bit more.
I am attempting to modify the boost ssl example located here:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/ssl/server.cpp
I am using g++ compiler and c++20
there is a lambda function in the do_accept() method in the server class:
acceptor_.async_accept(
     [this](const boost::system::error_code& error, tcp::socket socket)
     {
       if (!error)
       {
         std::make_shared<session>(
             boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>(
               std::move(socket), context_))->start();
       }

       do_accept();
     });

I would like to change the lambda function to a class method.
My method is:
void server::acceptHandler(const boost::system::error_code& error, tcp::socket socket) {
...
}

When I try to substitute to this:
acceptor_.async_accept(boost::bind(&server::acceptHandler, this,     boost::asio::placehoders::error, tcp::socket));
I get "error: expected primary-expression before ')' token" on the ')' after tcp::socket
I also tried:
acceptor_.async_accept(boost::bind(&server::acceptHandler, this, boost::asio::placehoders::error, boost::placeholders:_2))
I get: "error: use of deleted function 'boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<Protocol,Executor>::basic_stream_socket<Protocol,Executor&>) [with Protocol = boost::asio::ip::tcp; Executor = boost::asio::any_io_executor'
What is the proper method of changing a lambda function to a method function.
Here is the full code for the accept handler:
void acceptHandler(const boost::system::error_code& error, tcp::socket socket) {
if (!error)
  {
    std::make_shared<session>(
        boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>(
          std::move(socket), context_))->start();
  }

 do_accept();
}

I get the "error: use of deleted function..." on the std::move(socket)

Is it really too much work to actually put it together? You know, like, fixing the missing include, the missing colon, the mistyped placehoders and the #include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>? Here you go: https://godbolt.org/z/K9nGqfeoM

I imagined some of the surrounding code:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace ssl  = asio::ssl;
using asio::ip::tcp;

struct session : std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
    session(boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket> s) : stream_(std::move(s)) {}
    void start() {
        std::cout << "Accepted connection from " << stream_.lowest_layer().remote_endpoint() << "\n";
        stream_.async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::server,
                                [self = shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code ec) {
                                    if (!ec) {
                                        self->do_read();
                                    } else {
                                        std::cerr << "Handshake failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                                    }
                                });
    }

  private:
    void do_read() {
        stream_.async_read_some(
            asio::buffer(data_),
            [self = shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
                if (!ec) {
                    std::cout << "Received " << bytes_transferred << " bytes\n";
                    self->do_read();
                } else {
                    std::cerr << "Read failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                }
            });
    }
    ssl::stream<tcp::socket> stream_;
    std::array<char, 1024>   data_;
};

struct Server {
    Server(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port) : acc_(ex, {{}, port}) {
        // TODO load certificate and private key
        do_accept();
    }

  private:
    void do_accept() {
        acc_.async_accept([this](boost::system::error_code const& error, tcp::socket socket) {
            if (!error) {
                std::make_shared<session>(ssl::stream<tcp::socket>(std::move(socket), context_))->start();
            }

            do_accept();
        });
    }
    tcp::acceptor acc_;
    ssl::context  context_{ssl::context::tlsv12};
};

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool ctx;

    Server srv(ctx.get_executor(), 8989);

    ctx.join();
}

Because I left the certificate as an exercise for the reader, this is about what it can do:

Changing the lambda
Now, I don't know why you want it, but you can:
void do_accept() {
    acc_.async_accept(std::bind( //
        &Server::on_accept, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
}

void on_accept(boost::system::error_code const& error, tcp::socket socket) {
    if (!error) {
        std::make_shared<session>(ssl::stream<tcp::socket>(std::move(socket), context_))->start();
    }

    do_accept();
}

Note that tcp::socket is a type, not a placeholder.

Thanks, I actually included the code by reference I'm using the boost example. Your solution was actually my 2nd attempt above.  After much staring I realized that my 2nd issue wasn't the lambda, but the 'std::move(socket)'  in the handler. I was spending too many hours staring I guess.  and didn't realize I had the lambda right.  On to figuring out why the std::move is throwing the  "error: use of deleted function 'boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<Protocol,Executor>::basic_stream_socket<Protocol,Executor&>) [with Protocol = boost::asio::ip::tcp; Executor = boost::asio::any_io_executor' error.

You still have that issue? It would help a lot if you included the actual code. Something tells me something is const (e.g. void mymemberfunction() const). Because const-objects cannot be told to move from, not even with std::move

The actual code is here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/ssl/server.cpp.  The only change  made was the bind to acceptHandler and copying the code block from the lambda to the accept handler.  I'm new to stack overflow, I'll edit the original to add the code block.

The obvious difference to me seems you're using Boost Bind, and I don't. Again, for move semantics, lambdas are clearly far superior. Easier on the compiler too, likely leads to better machine code.

Sorry, I've been working on this too long, I missed the boost::bind and std::bind.  That solved the issue.  Thanks so much!  I'm going to take a break.  The main reason I am doing this is to extend what I know.  I appreciate your time.  Thanks again!

Cheers! And, always include the complete code, that shortens the answer cycle by about a factor 5!
